# Not shown renderText in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem in R Shiny.

1. Select Folder
2. Input Filename
3. Search file in the folder
4. When the file is not in the folder, show an error message in Shiny and in console

```
if (length(Fnum)==0) {
        print("File does not exists!")
        output$errormsg=renderText({"File does not exists! Pause 3min"})
        Sys.sleep(180)
      }
```

The error message is shown in console, but not shown in Shiny.
However, When the file exists, the message is shown properly.
It's very strange, I don't understand why the message is not shown only when the file does not exists.

What is happen?

Thank you for your help!

The following code is all;

server.R

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(stringi)

function(input, output, session) {  
  
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = volumes, session = session, restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
  
  output$directorypath <- renderPrint({
    if (is.integer(input$directory)) {
      cat("No directory has been selected (shinyDirChoose)")
    } else {
      parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)
    }
  })
  
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })  
  
  mytime<-reactiveValues(inc=0, timer=reactiveTimer(2000), started=FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$ab1, {
    mytime$started<-TRUE
  })
  
  
  
  observe({
    mytime$timer()
    
    if(isolate(mytime$started)){
      mytime$inc<-isolate(mytime$inc)+1
      
      res=0
      
      while (res==0) {
        Fnum=grep(paste0("1",stri_trans_nfkc(input$filename)," test.xls"), dir())
        
        if (length(Fnum)==0) {
          print("File does not exists!")
          output$errormsg=renderText({"File does not exists! Pause 3min"})
          Sys.sleep(180)
        }else{
          
          dlist=dir()
          Fname=dlist[Fnum]
          print(Fname)
          fn=paste0(path1(),"/",Fname)
          
          output$errormsg=renderText({paste0("File ", Fname," exists!")})
          res=1
        }
      }
      print(paste0("Filepath=",fn))
    }
  })
}
```

ui.R

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Program "), 
  
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select a directory ----
      tags$hr(),
      strong("Select directory:"),
      br(),
      shinyDirButton("directory", "Folder select", "Please select a folder"),
      textInput("filename","Input filename. ", ""),
      actionButton("ab1","START",class = "btn-warning")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      strong("Directory Path:"),
      br(),
      verbatimTextOutput("directorypath"),
      h4(textOutput("errormsg")),
      
      
    )
    
  )
)
```

Comment: are you sure the App code you provided works directly? I wasn't able to make it run in a new session / script.

Comment: @Waldi Thank you for your comment , I modified my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@YBS
Sorry for my poor explanation. This program is related for another program. This is for analyze the data which another program produced. So, this program needs to wait until the file from another program is produced. Therefore by using mytime ,this program is repeated until it finds the file.
However, I got the result that I had expected by modifying as  the following. Thank you for your advice again.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = volumes, session = session, restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
  
  output$directorypath <- renderPrint({
    if (is.integer(input$directory)) {
      cat("No directory has been selected (shinyDirChoose)")
    } else {
      parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)
    }
  })
  
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })  
  
  mytime<-reactiveValues(inc=0, timer=reactiveTimer(200), started=FALSE)
  #observeEvent(input$ab1, {
  observe({
    if (input$ab1==0){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      mytime$started<-TRUE
   # }
    
  # })
  # 
  # observe({
    mytime$timer()
    
    if(mytime$started){
      mytime$inc<-isolate(mytime$inc)+1
      
      #res=0
      
      #while (res==0) {
        req(input$filename)
        if (is.null(input$filename)) {
          return(NULL)
        }else{
          userfile <- paste0(path1(),"/",input$filename)
          if (file.exists(userfile)) {
            fn=paste0("Filepath=",path1(),"/",input$filename)
            output$errormsg <- renderText({
              if (file.exists(userfile)) {
                paste0("File ", input$filename," exists!")
              }else return(NULL)
            })
            #res=1
          }else {
            print("File does not exist!")
            output$errormsg=renderText({
              if (file.exists(userfile)) {
                return(NULL)
              }else{
                paste0("File ", input$filename," does not exist!")
              }
            })
            fn=paste0("No file named ", input$filename, " in ", path1()," folder")
          }
        }
        
      #}
      print(paste0(fn))
    }
   }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your `Fnum` to work. I made it an `observeEvent`, as it is better to check after writing the file name. After some modification to server function it works. You can add the counter and timers, if necessary.  Try this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = volumes, session = session, restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
  
  output$directorypath <- renderPrint({
    if (is.integer(input$directory)) {
      cat("No directory has been selected (shinyDirChoose)")
    } else {
      parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)
    }
  })
  
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })  
  
  mytime<-reactiveValues(inc=0, timer=reactiveTimer(200), started=FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$ab1, {
    if (input$ab1==0){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      mytime$started<-TRUE
    }
    
  # })
  # 
  # observe({
    mytime$timer()
    
    if(mytime$started){
      mytime$inc<-isolate(mytime$inc)+1
      
      #res=0
      
      #while (res==0) {
        req(input$filename)
        if (is.null(input$filename)) {
          return(NULL)
        }else{
          userfile <- paste0(path1(),"/",input$filename)
          if (file.exists(userfile)) {
            fn=paste0("Filepath=",path1(),"/",input$filename)
            output$errormsg <- renderText({
              if (file.exists(userfile)) {
                paste0("File ", input$filename," exists!")
              }else return(NULL)
            })
            #res=1
          }else {
            print("File does not exist!")
            output$errormsg=renderText({
              if (file.exists(userfile)) {
                return(NULL)
              }else{
                paste0("File ", input$filename," does not exist!")
              }
            })
            fn=paste0("No file named ", input$filename, " in ", path1()," folder")
          }
        }
        
      #}
      print(paste0(fn))
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
It's useful for me,but I'm facing to a new problem.
mytime$timer() is included in ovserveEvent, so reactiveValue named mytime does not work properly.
In your code, if the target fie does not exist, this code will be similar to terminate. However I want to wait until the file exists by using "mytime".
Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: From this example code, it is not clear why you need `mytime`. The program works without it.  You can remove the section where it is checking target file and returning NULL when it does not exist. Now you can state `if (!is.null(input$filename)) {…}` and then `output$errormsg`.